# Adding timestamp to javascript file disables caching of this file?

Tags: javascript, caching

I had this script in `<head>` of my website:

```
function check_messages() {
$('#messages').load('/check.php?tt='+(new Date()).getTime(),
function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
if(responseText != "") {
$("html,body").scrollTop("messages",0);
}
});
}
var auto_refresh = setInterval(check_messages, 180000);
```

Now I moved this function to external javascript file. The file is about 20 KB.

This script contains timestamp and I want to be sure that browsers will use cached version of this javascript? Will they? I don't want them to load the whole 20 KB script again and again.

Comment: Why are you adding a timestamp?  Usually the whole point is to be a "cache buster".

Comment: You should do that on the serverside, checking a timestamp to see that no new messages have been added, and return a response that only includes new messages etc.

Comment: I have read that without timestamp the script may show the cached version of check.php. I am wrong?

Comment: Ahh... so you're worried about the script itself not being cached because it in turn requests a non-cached check.php?  If that's the case, no worries.  As long as you have the appropriate caching headers configured on the server there's nothing about your `.load()` call that will mess with the script itself being cached.

Comment: The javascript itself needs to be cached but it may not show cached result of check.php file.

Comment: just discovered that browser does not cache this javascript at all. I tried to remove this function and checked server's logfiles. On each page refresh browser sends request to the server for this .js file. Any ideas?

Comment: hmmm... I included this javascript in the website in this way: <script type="text/javascript" src="/h.js?v=4"></script> and browser does not cache it. I removed v=4 and browses cached it. I am surprised. Many websites add values to .css and .js files to force them reload after changes. I didn't know that this causes non-caching.

Comment: @user1692255 The better way to cache them is make the URL/mapping as `/4/h.js`

Comment: Thanks lan. I changed it already. Now looks that the browser caches my script even with added timestamp.